# Cannot set property 'passwordStrength' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code, and getting javascript error on first line:

Error Is "Cannot set property 'passwordStrength' of undefined "

Code:

```
window.myProject.passwordStrength = function ($, window, document) {
var desc = new Array();
desc[0] = "Very Weak";
desc[1] = "Weak";
desc[2] = "Better";
desc[3] = "Medium";
desc[4] = "Strong";
desc[5] = "Very Strong";
return {
    maxScore: 5,
    allowedScore: 4,
    getStrengthDescription: function(score){
        return desc[score];
    },
    getStrength: function(password){


        var score = 0;

        //if password bigger than 6 give 1 point
        if (password.length > 6) score++;

        //if password has both lower and uppercase characters give 1 point  
        if ((password.match(/[a-z]/)) && (password.match(/[A-Z]/))) score++;

        //if password has at least one number give 1 point
        if (password.match(/\d+/)) score++;

        //if password has at least one special caracther give 1 point
        if (password.match(/.[!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,?,_,~,-,(,)]/)) score++;

        //if password bigger than 12 give an other 1 point
        if (password.length > 12) score++;
        return score;
    }
};
}(jQuery, window, document);
```

I am calling this in my page as:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var passwordStrength = window.myProject.passwordStrength();
            $('#Password').keyup(function () {
                var strength = passwordStrength.getStrength($(this).val());
}
</script>
```

Comment: what is `window.myProject`?

Comment: What's your question exactly?

Comment: The error message should be quite self-explanatory. `window.myProject` is undefined (i.e. it doesn't exist).

Comment: Why the double document ready? And why are you doing `window.marchnad.passwordStrength` when yours is called `window.myProject.passwordStrength`

Comment: how to resolve this. Actually i am new in javascript

Comment: @putvande.. type error. this is window.myProject.passwordStrength

Comment: am i stoned or istn he closing two ready functions plus the keyup function with one single curly bracket ?

Comment: window.myProject.passwordStrength is my custom namespace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to define the object before you define new properties to that object

```
window.myProject = {};
window.myProject.passwordStrength = function ($, window, document) {
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/vYJVe/)

Comment: now it gives error Property 'passwordStrength' of object #<Object> is not a function

Comment: That's because it's not a function. You have an IIFE that executes right away, and returns an object, so the value of `window.myProject.passwordStrength` is simply the object you returned, not a function.

Comment: @Sami - You're welcome. Note how the function is really an IIFE, that is executed immediately, and then returns the object with the other methods.

Comment: Yes i got that, Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest you to do it otherwise. Simpler & cleaner.

**jsfiddle :** http://jsfiddle.net/VmAHF/

**js :**

```
(function ($) {
    var desc = [ 'Very Weak', 'Weak', 'Better', 'Medium', 'Strong', 'Very Strong' ];

    var maxScore = 5,
        allowedScore = 4;

    $.fn.getStrength = function (password) {
        var password = $(this).val(),
            score = 0;

        //if password bigger than 6 give 1 point
        if (password.length > 6) score++;

        //if password has both lower and uppercase characters give 1 point  
        if ((password.match(/[a-z]/)) && (password.match(/[A-Z]/))) score++;

        //if password has at least one number give 1 point
        if (password.match(/\d+/)) score++;

        //if password has at least one special caracther give 1 point
        if (password.match(/.[!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,?,_,~,-,(,)]/)) score++;

        //if password bigger than 12 give an other 1 point
        if (password.length > 12) score++;
        return score;
    };

    $.fn.getStrengthDescription = function() {
        return desc[$(this).getStrength()];
    };
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#password').keyup(function () {
        $('#strength').text($(this).getStrength());
        $('#strength-description').text($(this).getStrengthDescription());
    });
});
```